# How can I use the HTML Editor with JSP content in Eclipse Luna? Getting Unsupported Content Type error

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, editor

When I open a JSP, I get a unsupported-content-type error telling me to see the Content Type preferences panel.

[image]

I open the Content Types Preferences page and check Text/HTML content types and see that *.jsp is a File Association, but all other associations are 'locked'.

[image]

From there I check the file association and click on *.jsp. Now I see that I've associated the HTML Editor with JSP pages and set it to default, but see that it is locked by HTML content type.

[image]

Can someone please explain how to properly associate the JSP editor with HTML content so that I get correct HTML editing with colorization and tag matching?

Comment: After making change you must restart eclipse

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. I now get the "unsupported content type" error while the Eclipse splash page is displayed.

Comment: I think it may be a bug :)

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse Juno installing the **JSF Tools**. You can find them in the [Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-ee-developer-tools-0), select only the features JSF Tools in the **Confirm Selected Features** window and install them. It associates the *.jsp, *.jsf... extensions with the JSP editor.

Try it in Luna